# Nextcloud client : No keychain service available

Tags: linux, slackware, gnome-keyring, nextcloud

I have installed the nextcloud-client package from [slackbuilds.org](https://slackbuilds.org/repository/14.2/network/nextcloud-client/), with qtkeychain, libgnome-keyring and gnome-keyring.

I run the daemon in my `.xinitrc` like explained on the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Keyring):

```
eval $(gnome-keyring-daemon --start)
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

And it is still not working (No keychain service available).
Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work by installing LXDM.

I think the ArchWiki is wrong because `gnome-keyring-daemon --start` does not actually start the daemon according to the man page:

```
-s, --start
       Connect to an already running daemon and initialize it. This is often used to
       complete initialization of a daemon that was started by PAM using the --login
       argument.
```

I guess LXDM is starting the daemon correctly now because it works.

Answer (score 7):

In Ubuntu 18.04 LTS it can be solved by installing `libgnome-keyring0`. Single `gnome-keyring` package is not enough for nextcloud.

Comment: Owncloud bug report: https://github.com/owncloud/client/issues/6500